# Error while using label to query database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to display rows in a GridView that match the ID which is cast into a Label. I get an error "Input string was not in a correct format" when I run this query.

```
Private Sub BindGrid()
        Dim constring As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connstr").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from [table] WHERE ID=@Label6")
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Label6", Label.Text)
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        GridView2.DataSource = dt
                        GridView2.DataBind()
                    End Using
                End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Here is the Code for Label:

```
 Public Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim Lnk As LinkButton = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton)
    Label6.Text = Lnk.Text
    LinkButton1_ModalPopupExtender.Show()
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? The ID is int.

The aspx code

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDummy" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="LinkButton1_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="lnkDummy" PopupControlID="Panel1"> </cc1:ModalPopupExtender> 
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="164px" Width="284px" BackColor="SlateGray" ><br /><br /> 
      <center><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
          <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    PageSize="2" AllowPaging="true">
              <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Comments" HeaderText="Comments" SortExpression="Comments" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Processed_By" HeaderText="Processed_By" SortExpression="Processed_By" />

        </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
      <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-md" Text="Close"/></center>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Show the aspx where you've added the `LinkButton1_Click` handler. Also, always use the correct type in the first place. Don't let the database guess the type of your parameter. ID seems to be an int value, so convert the string to int in VB.NET. What is the value of `Label.Text`? Use the debugger if you don't know it.

Comment: Assuming the line `Parameters.Add` is a typo and you meant `Parameters.AddWithValue': You are passing a non-integer string when the query expects an integer parameter - unless `ID` is `varchar`. Parse the input to an int before sending it to the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no overload of [`Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes parameter name and value.
Change this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Label6", Label.Text)
```

to this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Label6", SqlDbType.int).value = Label.Text
```

Comment: Instead of passing the text directly to the parameter, the OP should try to parse it first in order to catch non-numeric values

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I would agree if it was a textbox. but it's a label, and that means that the text property is populated either in design time or in run time by the program itself. I assume that the OP is already sure that it's an Integer.

Comment: I've already used the following: ` 'cmd.Parameters.Add("@Label6", SqlDbType.Int)

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("Label6", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Label6.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Label6", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Label6.Text)

                    'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Label6", Convert.ToInt16(Label6.Text))

                    'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Label6", Label6.Text)`

Comment: @Zahed please post code in the question, making it clear what you've tried and what the results are. I see 5 different ways to add a parameter that should have resulted in different errors. Also, *is* the content of the label a number? If not, the `Convert.ToInt32/16` calls would fail, as they should